# preg_match can not find the "Dash" in an email

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using the following FUNCTION to extract email address from text.

```
function is_valid_email($email) {
    if (preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.([a-z]){2,4})$/',$emailss)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

It is working very smoothly, but on problem:
an email with "dash" is not working:

for example:

`info-test@web-site.com` comes out: `test@web`

Please advise.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the built-in [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`?

Comment: @Lix this function is not fool-proof, imo. The comments in the doc also suggest that. http://isemail.info/ provides a library which adheres to the specs and verifies a host of possible email addresses.

Comment: It works pretty fine for me. Is `$email` and `$emailss` typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dash has special meaning in regular expression. So cant be used directly and need to be escaped using backslash. following is updated code:

```
function is_valid_email($email) {
    if (preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9\-]+(\.[_a-z0-9\-]+)*@[a-z0-9\-]+(\.[a-z0-9\-]+)*(\.([a-z]){2,4})$/',$emailss)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to escape the dash when it is at the begining or at the end of the character class.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the dash character, as it has a special meaning (range) in the used context:

`[_a-z0-9\-]`

Comment: There's no need to escape the dash when it is at the begining or at the end of the character class.

Answer (score 1):

There are *myriads* of problems with that e-mail validation regexp. For example, it won't pass any of perfectly valid modern national TLDs and it honestly thinks that TLD has maximum 4 letters in it. It doesn't allow arbitrary number of dots `.` in user account part, it doesn't allow pluses `+`, etc.

Generally, a good practice of validating e-mails boils down to:

1. Minimal validation - just check that there's `@` there and that's all.
2. Just send that e-mail - don't check anything else. If it will be sent - then it's indeed a valid e-mail.

For more details, take a look at http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ or any similar articles.